# Is there a single English word for “苦笑”?

Tags: translation

“苦笑” is usually defined as a forced smile, a sickly smile, a wry smile, and a bitter smile. Is there a single English word that means the same or closest to “苦笑”? Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no single word. But isn't this a question about the English language, not the Chinese language?

Comment: Not about the Chinese language

Comment: I would've put this down as a comment.

Comment: I have left a comment on one of your other questions regarding you submitting translation questions from Chinese to English. Questions like this are offtopic on the Chinese Language se site. You will have better luck posting it on english.se.

Answer (score 1):

For example.
You are a Chinese.
Your breakfast is not safe. N, not breakfast. it should be dinner.
You can't sleep well in each night.
You pay a lot of work day and day but you get less and less money.

You didn't have enough time to play, to laugh, to do every thing you want to do.

In this evening, you are watching TV, you are eating the hardest bread in this word, and you find there is a girl in the news, she said:
"as a report, Chinese is the happiest person in this world."

"What a good joke!" you smiled. just with a little sad.

Someone take a photo for you in this moment.

The title of this photo should be:
someone is 苦笑ing

Comment: the question is about how to translate "苦笑" into a single English word, not about the explanation of "苦笑" itself.